# Is this For loop in javascript the way you translate into jquery $.each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, each

I am just interested to know if this is how you translate it from javascript to jquery. If not, could you please modify it so I can understand?

The javascript code is:

```
function blaAll() {
hideSomething();

var formEl = document.getElementById("idForm");
var inputs = formEl.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    dosomething(inputs[i]);
}
}
```

The jquery code:

```
function blaAll() {
    hideSomething();
    var formEl = $("#idForm");
    var inputs = formEl.$("input");
    $.each(inputs,function(i, 0)) {
        dosomething(inputs[i])
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Not really you have to define two arguments you pass to anonymous function.
First is `index` eg your `i`, second is `object` itself.
 Since you have object already you do not need to use it like `inputs[i]` although you could.

```
function validateAll() {
    hideSomething();
    var formEl = $("#idForm");
    var inputs = formEl.$("input");
    $.each(inputs,function(i, item) {
        dosomething(item);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `$.each` function, the callback is provided a key and value, so it's actually wrong. What it should be is:

```
$.each(inputs,function(key, val)) {
    dosomething(val)
}
```